# Oracle Trigger: Unable to Update Table Using Subquery or Variables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers, subquery

I am encountering an issue with an Oracle trigger where I am attempting to update a table based on a subquery result or a declared variable. The trigger is designed to execute before an update on the 'BOOKS' table, specifically when the 'Status' column is set to 'Canceled'. The problematic section of the trigger involves updating the 'FEE' column in the 'CANCELLATIONS' table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Cancel_Fee
BEFORE UPDATE ON BOOKS 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        C_Date DATE;
        A_Date DATE;
        CalculatedFee NUMBER;
        date_diff NUMBER;
        Cancel_date DATE;
        Apt_Date DATE;
    BEGIN
        IF :NEW.Status = 'Canceled' THEN
            -- Issue arises here
            SELECT C.Cancel_date INTO C_Date FROM CANCELLATIONS C WHERE Cn_ID = :NEW.Apt_ID;
            A_date := Apt_Date;
            UPDATE Cancellations
            SET FEE = (SELECT TO_NUMBER(c_date - A_date) FROM dual)
            WHERE CN_ID = :NEW.Apt_ID;
        END IF;
    END;
END;
/
```

The trigger works when I provide a direct value like 1 or 's' for the 'FEE' column. However, it fails to update when I use a subquery or a variable declared within the trigger. I would appreciate guidance on resolving this issue and understanding why the subquery or variable assignment is not functioning as expected.

Comment: You define the `Apt_Date` local variable; where should its value be set from?

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to need any PL/SQL variables as the `cancel_date` is in the `cancellations` table and you can access that value during the `UPDATE` of the same table and then the `Apt_Date` appears to be part of the `:NEW` record that is passed to the trigger (or else it is a variable you have never assigned a value to).

Which means that you can use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Cancel_Fee
BEFORE UPDATE ON BOOKS 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.Status = 'Canceled' THEN
    UPDATE Cancellations
    SET    fee = GREATEST(Cancel_date - :NEW.Apt_date, 0)
    WHERE  CN_ID = :NEW.Apt_ID;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Which, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE books (apt_id, apt_date, status) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-01', CAST('New' AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE cancellations (cn_id, cancel_date, fee) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-11', 0 FROM DUAL;
```

And you perform the `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE books
SET    status = 'Canceled'
WHERE  apt_id = 1;
```

Then the `cancellations` table contains:

| CN_ID | CANCEL_DATE | FEE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1970-01-11 00:00:00 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hYCcaiKS)

---

#### Update

Based on your update, you still do not need PL/SQL variables and should do it all in a single SQL statement rather than continually context-switching between SQL and PL/SQL and using intermediate variables.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Cancel_Fee
BEFORE UPDATE ON BOOKS 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.Status = 'Canceled' THEN
    UPDATE Cancellations
    SET    fee = GREATEST(
                   Cancel_date
                   - ( SELECT Apt_date
                       FROM   APPOITMENT
                       WHERE  Apt_ID = :NEW.Apt_ID
                     ),
                   0
                 )
    WHERE  CN_ID = :NEW.Apt_ID;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OWNgtplp)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was A_date := Apt_Date; line where i try to set the variable A_date to Apt_date while Apt_date is not a column in the Books table, to fix it i just needed to select it from the appointment table like so:

```
 SELECT A.Apt_date
    INTO A_DATE
    FROM APPOITMENT A
    WHERE Apt_ID = :NEW.Apt_ID;
```

Comment: Using lots of queries and storing the values in PL/SQL variables is going to be inefficient. You should do it all in a single SQL statement as part of the `UPDATE` statement.